# How to make a User Profile in Ubuntu 16.04 have very limited access

Tags: 16.04, vmware-view

I'm a rather new user to Linux/Ubuntu and have been tasked at my job to create a local user profile in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS that will only allow for opening one application "VMWare Horizon View Client" which we want set on the Desktop for easy connection to the users Virtual Machines. This means restricting access to everything else except the ability to log off of the profile.

I'm sure there are many steps involved and much required to be able to do this. Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

AppArmor and SELinux may work as suggested, I would need to dig into the suggestions further. However, I am unsure as the goal of what I am trying to do is essentially setup a "kiosk" type profile that our users would login to and basically only have the ability to open the application "VMware Horizon View Client" that is on their desktop, see if they have an Internet connection, and log out of the profile. Just about locking down all access to just about everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict User To Specific Apps and Restrict Writing Except When Using Said Apps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101420/restrict-user-to-specific-apps-and-restrict-writing-except-when-using-said-apps)